# Is there any defined way of choosing what variable to use for memoization in any given problem?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, optimization, data-structures, memoization

For example, if we have the following problem:

Given a set of coins - [1,2,5] and an amount - 11. Find minimum number of coins needed to make 11.

We can use recursion to explore the state space. For example, the root is empty and we start at index 0 of the coin array. From the root, we can either choose to take the coin 1 (index 0 of coins array) or not take the coin 1 and continue to explore the state space recursively.

But how do we choose what variable to use for memoization? Is there any defined generic way of choosing it?

In this problem, intuitively, I chose the following variable to use for memoization:

**tuple key:** (Sum of coins, index of coin array we are exploring)
**Value:** number of coins

But it does not work.

Comment: Does it have to be done recursively?

Comment: I am just trying to implement memoization for the problem using dictionary. Just hoping to understand how would one go on to choose what variable to use as 'key' for memoization.

Answer (score 1):

The hard part is finding the recursion. So you first need to find a solution using recursion, and the rest is easy.

Generally, we can try to express the answer as a function. For example, let `f(x)` equals the minimum number of coins needed to make x. So the answer is `f(11)`.

Next, we try to find some recursion and base cases. In this case, `f(x) = min(f(x-1), f(x-2), f(x-5)) + 1`, `f(0) = 0` and `f(x) = inf` if `x < 0`.

You can implement this function before memoization and test with small inputs to see if it is working.

When the recursion part is done, memo parameters are the parameters of the function that affects the result. In this case, there is only one parameter and it is the parameter you should use in your memo.